# How to reduce array size without creating new?

Tags: java, arrays, resize, runtime

I am using array for storing a kind of object. I created an array of some fixed size

```
int arr[]=new int[n];
```

Now after processing this array i want to free upto 75% of the memory from this array(now only n/4 elements are useful). So what my question is, since n is very large and i wish not to hold larger memory than useful, **How can i reduce size of array at runtime without copying to new array of size n/4(Is it even possible or not?)**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not possible. You cannot change the length of an array after you initialise it.

What you can do is  create another array with suitable size and make this large array eligible for Garbage Collector.

Best is to use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if you are allowed to do that.

Comment: ya thats correct to copy the useful values to newly created array, but in my case the number of records are nearly 2000 and after some processing only 500 records are useful. That's why this question arise. Thanks!

Comment: `ArrayList` isn't really useful here, either; you'd have to first shuffle the entries to keep to the front, and then call `trimToSize`. Better just to create a new array and copy the entries there.

Comment: @uniquephase declare a new array by getting the size from large array and copy those elements to new array.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ my data is too big that if i create a new array and copy data in it, it make my program bit slow and this change is significant. So at this situation i have to work with the whole size of array.

Comment: @uniquephase Wait. This new array won't cause too much memory creation since it holds the references on original array elements, unless you create new objects with help of current elements. And having 500 new objects won't cause that much performance difference unless it's carrying too much amount of data. Once you create this new array, you can make the old array avail for GC right ?? So that you can free up memory.

Comment: actually these objects are maps of integer to list. :p

Comment: 2000 elements is _tiny_.  Copying 500 of those is not really that significant unless you're doing it a *lot.*

Comment: My problem with using ArrayList is you can't have an ArrayList of primitives... 

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at all. Eventhough you are using collections for creating they are copying the array elements to newer size array if the array size exceeds!

Comment: Shriram if you have faced such situation what could be the directions to think about for memory optimization ?

Comment: create a new array with the actual size and copy the elements to that array.

Answer (score 1):

No, Once you created an array then its size is fixed. You cant change it at run time. For your current scenario you can copy your useful elements to new array. Or just keep the array don't care about the memory.

Comment: ya i got it, my direction of thinking was not correct.